# Updating HOCON files using pyhocon

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a HOCON file template with some property-like configuration. This file is updated for different "names"(provided bu user input) and uploaded . I'm trying to build the hocon file by pulling the template, updating the necessary values and upload the updated file.

```
deployment {
      proxy {
        // Name has to be replaced with the name of the project
        cluster.NAME {
          property1 = [a_list]
          property2.host = "hostname"
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm able to update values using pyhocon:

```
from pyhocon import ConfigFactory


conf = ConfigFactory.parse_string(hocon_file_template)
host = "something-TEST.trial.com"
conf.put('deployment.proxy.cluster.NAME.property2.host', host)
new = HOCONConverter.convert(conf, "hocon")
```

However, I need to replace "NAME" in "cluster.NAME" with the user_input, say "TEST". I tried to change NAME using put , but that appends to the cluster tree as opposed to updating NAME to "TEST"

```
host_key = 'deployment.proxy.cluster.' ".{}.property2.host"
conf.put(host_key.format(user_input), host)
```

How do I update NAME to the input value(In this example, "TEST")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to use pop to remove remove the specified key i.e "NAME" and add the key "TEST" to the tree using put.

```
from pyhocon import ConfigFactory


conf = ConfigFactory.parse_string(hocon_file_template)
# Remove NAME from template
conf.pop("deployment.proxy.cluster.NAME")
host = "something-TEST.trial.com"
# Use Test to update required properties
conf.put('deployment.proxy.cluster.TEST.property2.host', host)
new = HOCONConverter.convert(conf, "hocon")
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the template from the config

```
deployment {
  proxy {
    // Name has to be replaced with the name of the project
    cluster {


    }
  }
}


project_name {
  property1 = [a_list]
  property2 {
    host = ${hostname}

  }
}
```

Create the configuration in a dictionary

```
from pyhocon import ConfigFactory

project_name = "cool_project"

props = {'hostname': 'localhost'}
runtime_conf = ConfigFactory.from_dict(props)

conf = runtime_conf.with_fallback(
    config="./app.conf",
    resolve=True,
)

conf.deployment.proxy.cluster[project_name] = conf.project_name
```

You can also get both configurations from files and resolve with the second.